# Send a variable to a remote server with ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

Im trying to do log into a file (in a remote server lets say /home/test/log.txt) what is stored in $var. Im trying with

```
ssh test@$192.168.1.35 "echo "var" >> /home/test/log.txt"
```

y also tried

```
 ssh test@$192.168.1.35 "echo "$var" >> log.txt"
```

but the both didnt work

any help?

Comment: `echo "$var" | ssh test@$192.168.1.35 "cat >> /home/test/log.txt"`

Comment: You're going to have to be more clear about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Im tryin to write in log.txt the content of $var

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using double quotes, so the variable expansion will happen locally. You should use single quotes, so that the command gets sent unaltered.

In the same way as `echo '$var'` gives `$var` while `echo "$var"` displays the contents, this way the server sees `$var` instead of the contents of the local `$var`.

So:

`ssh test@$192.168.1.35 'echo $var >> /home/test/log.txt'`

will create a file on the remote computer, with the value of the remote `$var` in it.

If you do

`ssh test@$192.168.1.35 'echo $var' >> /home/test/log.txt`

you get a file on the local computer with the value of the remote `$var` in it.

If you do

`ssh test@$192.168.1.35 "echo $var >> /home/test/log.txt"`

it stores the value of your local `$var` in the file on the remote system.

(Also, if it only involves the remote system, you should probably use a shell script, or maybe cron if you want it to happen automatically.)

Comment: are you sure i must startwith " and end with ' ?

Comment: No, that was a typo. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ssh test@192.168.1.35 "echo '$var' >> /home/test/log.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
ssh test@$192.168.1.35 'echo "$var" >> /home/test/log.txt'
```

This should work. Assuming `var` was set on your computer and not the remote.

Comment: This will use `$var` from remote host. `echo "$var" >> /home/test/log.txt` will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct way to put some text from a linux machine in an already existing file on another linux machine:

```
echo 'text' | ssh test@$192.168.1.35 'cat >> /remote_file_path'
```